# If $V=\mathrm{span}(v_1,...,v_n)$ a $\mathbb C G$-module, why don't we have $V=\langle u_1\rangle\oplus\dotsb\oplus\langle u_n\rangle$?

Tags: group-theory

Let $V=\langle v_1,...,v_n\rangle=:\mathrm{span}(v_1,...,v_n)$ a vector space over a field $\mathbb K$.

Q1) Do you agree that
\begin{align}
V &{}=\langle v_1\rangle\oplus \dotsb \oplus\langle v_n\rangle \\
&{}=\langle v_1,v_2\rangle\oplus\dotsb\oplus\langle v_{n-1},v_n\rangle \\
&{}=\langle v_1,v_2\rangle\oplus \langle v_3,v_4,v_5\rangle\oplus \langle v_6\rangle\oplus\dotsb\oplus\langle v_{n-2}\rangle\oplus\langle v_{n-1},v_n\rangle\ \ ?
\end{align}
I think it's correct.

Q2) Let now $G$ a group, and let see $V$ as a $\mathbb CG$-module. Let $V=\langle u_g\mid g\in G\rangle$. Why can't I do all those composition as well? To me it wouldn't be a problem to write $$V=\langle u_{g_1}\rangle\oplus\dotsb\oplus\langle u_{g_{|G|}}\rangle,$$
but a teacher told me it was wrong.

Comment: Since it might get lost in the comments, please note @TobiasKildetoft's remark (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1833638/if-v-spanv-1-v-n-a-mathbb-c-g-module-why-dont-we-dont-have-v-u-1#comment3748586_1833643) that a spanning set need not be a basis, so even your first question (where the notation is a bit confusing:  is $n$ even or odd?  What is the pattern hidden by $\dotsb$?) can fail.  For the second, note that a $\mathbb CG$-module need not have a basis, or even a spanning set, of cardinality $\lvert G\rvert$.

Answer (score 2):

**Q1)** Yes you right.

**Q2)** The problem is that the $\left< u_{g_i}\right>$ are not necessarily a $\mathbb CG-$module. To have the property of $\mathbb CG-$module, they need to be $G-$stable, i.e. $gu_{g_i}\in \left<u_{g_i}\right>$ for all $g\in G$.

Notice that in both cases, the decomposition in simple module are unique (to isomorphism), but irreducible for vector space over field have dimension 1 whereas for $\mathbb C G-$module, the dimension can be higher).

Comment: His Q1 is not even quite correct in the stated form. And his Q2 is also lacking several details to make it really meaningful (for example it seems from his question that all vector spaces should have the same dimension as the order of some arbitrary group).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: His Q1) is correct. I don't really understand what is problematic for you here. For Q2) I agree, I think he makes the confusion between the vector space $\mathbb CG(*,\cdot )$ generated by the element of the group (where $*$ is the law of the group), and a vector space $V$ with a structure of $\mathbb CG-$module. But in the case of the regular $\mathbb CG-$module, the question makes sense (and I think, it's what the OP wants to talk about) that's why I didn't raise this. But you right, it's important to raise this detail :)

Comment: In his Q1 he mixes up $v$'s and $u$'s and only assumes that the $u$'s span the space, not that they are a basis. But I agree that the intended meaning of that part is clear.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: Oh yes, you right ! I even didn't pay attention to it. I will edit his question.

Comment: I think that the confused notation is not the only issue.  One can decompose a $\mathbb CG$-module just as a vector space if desired, so it's not necessarily a problem that $\langle u_g\rangle$ is not a submodule; but it's not true that its dimension must be the order of $G$, as @TobiasKildetoft points out, and so a direct-sum decomposition, even just as vector spaces, each of whose $\lvert G\rvert$-many terms is (appears?) one-dimensional might not exist.

Comment: (Pardon:  "its dimension" should be "the dimension of $V$" (not of $\langle u_g\rangle$).)

Comment: @LSpice: For the regular $\mathbb CG$ module, the dimension has in fact to be the order of $G$ (since $V=\left<e_g\mid g\in G\right>$. But since it's not mentioned $V$ can be not the regular $\mathbb CG-$ module (and you right, the dimension if $V$ is not necessarily $|G|$), but the answer is easy to adapt.

Comment: @Surb, I'm sorry that I don't understand your comment (did a 'not' migrate somewhere?).  Certainly it is *possible* that a representation of $G$ has dimension the order of $G$; I didn't mean to deny that.  However, if it doesn't have that dimension, then it doesn't have a basis of size the order of $G$; and, if it has a greater dimension, then it doesn't even have a spanning set of that size.

Comment: Also, the statement "the decomposition in simple module[s is] unique" isn't quite true; the multiplicity of a given irreducible is well determined, but not which vectors sit in which copy.  (Think, for example, of $\mathbb C(1, 0) \oplus \mathbb C(0, 1) = \mathbb C(1, 1) \oplus \mathbb C(1, -1)$ as representations of the trivial group.)  All that is well determined is the sum of *all* copies of a given irreducible, *i.e.*, the corresponding isotypic component—which I'm sure is what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

Your question gets to the core question of representation theory:

Given a group $G$, what, up to isomorphism are the irreducible $\mathbb{C}[G]$-modules $V$?

In this case, a $\mathbb{C}[G]$-module $V$ is irreducible if the only $\mathbb{C}[G]$-submodules $W \subseteq V$ are $V$ and $\{0\}$.

When $G$ is the trivial group, there is a unique irreducible module, namely $\mathbb{C}$ itself. Hence an $n$-dimensional vector space $V$ may be decomposed as $V=\bigoplus_{i=1}^{n}V_i$, where $V_i \cong \mathbb{C}$, for all $i \in [n]$.

However, when $G$ is not the complex numbers, the answer is not as straightforward, and the question of what the irreducible $\mathbb{C}[G]$-modules are has been an active area of research for a long time now. As Surb points out, an irreducible $\mathbb{C}[G]$-module may have dimension greater than one.

As an example, let $G=S_3$ be the symmetric group on $3$ letters, and let $V=span_{\mathbb{C}} \{2-1,3-1\}$, where $S_3$ acts on $\{1,2,3\}$ in the obvious way. Then $V$ is naturally a $\mathbb{C}[S_3]$-module, as well as irreducible, though $dim_{\mathbb{C}}V=2$.

Comment: Are you claiming that the complex numbers has just a single irreducible representation?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Is it not the case that the only irreducible $\mathbb{C}$ module is one-dimensional?

Comment: Yes, but that is a completely different statement than the group $\mathbb{C}$ having this property. I think you meant to say "when $G$ is the trivial group" instead.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft right, will edit!

Comment: @leibnewtz, while anyone familiar with the subject will be able to figure what you mean, I think that it may be confusing to someone just starting to learn the subject to contemplate a vector space in which $1 + 1 \ne 2$.  Maybe the standard $e_i$ notation would be better?